# Has Allah ever given a creature the power(s) to do something miracle like Greek gods?

Tags: imaan

I believe that Allah is the one and only god. I have read that Dajjal has the power to command the sky to  rain. (Sunan Ibn Majah 4077) So, I have this question. I am wondering if, in the past, Allah has ever created creatures or a creature that was under Allah’s will, and Allah gave them the power(s) to do something miracle like Greek gods in order to test humanity’s faith or anything.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What powers or miracles has the Greek gods? They were nothing but stones that the Greek pagans worshiped.

Comment: Allah mentioned in the qur'an people mostly messengers He gave some specific "abilities".

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost, I think we should get it out of the way that the Greek gods you're referring to were what pagans used to worship. Just like how the arabs in the time of the Prophet Muhammad (saw) used to worship idols. Their existence is not real except in fictional books and movies. Believing anything on this planet is near godlike is shirk, something that should be avoided or you will be avoided Paradise. Second of all, Dajjal will only have the power to bring down rain and vegetation because that's one of his deceptions against human kind. The resurrecting part about the hadith is actually shayateen (evil jinns) who manifest themselves into people's dead relatives to fool them into thinking Dajjal is divine. No one on this planet has ever compared to Allah swt. For He is the Almighty "And proclaim: Praise be to Allah, Who has not taken unto Himself a son, and Who has no partner in the Sovereignty, nor has He (need for) any protecting friend through dependence. (17:111)

I hope this answer finds you well. Jazakallah khairen and have a wonderful rest of your day!

Comment: Jazakallah khairen. Your answer helped me a lot. But I'm still curious a bit. How is the power of Dajjal that he will be a able to command the sky to rain and vegetation is different from godlike? And how can I know that this kind of deceitful incidents caused by someone else who is similar to Dajjal did or didn't happen in the past because of Allah's intention?